# How to pass Nexus credentials to Azure DevOps server

Tags: maven, azure-devops, nexus

I'm building Java project on Azure pipeline. I've added a Maven task to deploy the project. How to pass Nexus credentials to Maven? I understand that we probably need to update settings.xml. Can anyone advise how to achieve that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with below configuration steps.

**(1)** Add a section in your `pom.xml` file to describe your Nexus repositories.

In your `pom.xml`, please set the `repository` to have the same `<id>` as the name specified in the task for Maven, so that it could be able to correctly authenticate the task.

For sample:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>MyNexus</id>
      <url>http://xxxxx/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>MyNexus.snapshots</id>
      <url>http://xxxxx/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

**(2)** Specify the credentials in `settings.xml`, so that Maven task could use it to access Nexus repositories.

Sample:

```
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>MyNexus</id>
      <username>${MyNexusUsername}</username>
      <password>${MyNexusPassword}</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

**(3)**  You can see, here I am using variables which can accept the values passed from `Maven` task. This is a secure way secure way and you can configure them as secret variables in Build pipeline. Just pass them in definition.

[image]

Then pass those variables in `Maven` task:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Merlin Liang for the answer. How do I update settings.xml on Azure DevOps Server? Can it be done through Azure DevOps GUI? On the Azure DevOps pipeline, when I select Maven Task, it shows me options to specify maven package, version etc but how to update the settings.xml file to add servers tag?

Comment: @java_ninja. Sorry for my missing. I forgot this key points. You can locate this setting file in your local by follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/maven/pom-and-settings?view=azure-devops-2019. Just do modify it locally.

Comment: @java_ninja. May I know how's the things going now? Do you get issue solved now?